# jQuery - Adding increasing number to image for each click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to create a notification counter for my app. For now, I want to add an increasing number **on top of an image** for each button click. How can this be achieved using jQuery?
[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aangsebo/)

HTML:

```
<img id="header_bell_notificator" class="show_notif" src="http://www.gsi.co.ir/Docs/Images/Red_Circle.png" alt="" width="30px">
<button id="kick_button">click this</button>
```

CSS:

```
.show_notif{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

JS:

```
var counter=0;
$( "#kick_button" ).click(function() {$("#header_bell_notificator").removeClass("show_notif");
    });
```

Comment: Try this http://jsfiddle.net/vk5j72s3/ You need additional div for counter

Comment: Thanks, but I need this number to be on the image itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/vk5j72s3/1/ just move counter to right position :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a few mods to your implementation...

- wrapper div for the image
- set `data-counter` attribute on wrapper
- show counter using `:before` pseudo-element

you could get something like this:

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aangsebo/8/)</kbd>

```js
var counter=0,
    $bellNotificator = $('#header_bell_notificator'),
    $bellNotificatorImg = $bellNotificator.find('img');

$( "#kick_button" ).click(function() {
    counter++;
    $bellNotificator.attr('data-counter', counter);
    $bellNotificatorImg.removeClass("show_notif");
});
```

```css
body {
    font-family: helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
}
#header_bell_notificator {
    float:left;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}
#header_bell_notificator:before {
    content: attr(data-counter);
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: .8em;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.show_notif{
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header_bell_notificator">
    <img class="show_notif" src="http://www.gsi.co.ir/Docs/Images/Red_Circle.png" alt="" width="30px" />
</div>
    
<button id="kick_button">click this</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

simply try it like this:

[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aangsebo/3/)

```
   $( "#kick_button" ).click(function() {
      var counter = parseInt($('.counter').html()) + 1;
      $('.counter').html(counter);
   });
```

and add a container called `<div class="counter">0</div>`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to move the image to the background of a  and then change its inner html.
Like this:

```
var counter=0;
$( "#kick_button" ).click(function() {
  counter++;
  $("#header_bell_notificator").removeClass("show_notif").html(counter);
});
```

Here's the [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rves7om5/1/)